# SQL query to query set (django) converter

Tags: postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, pgadmin-4

See below for my query editor

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(date_created) AS "Last_purchase" FROM public.accounts_order GROUP BY customer_id;
```

How will this look as a queryset on my django views?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would look something like this:

```
Accounts_order.objects.values('customer_id') \ 
.annotate(last_created=Max('date_created'))
```

Comment: I get the error "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'"

Comment: Try now, had to remove the group_by. Objects.values('customer_id') is the group_by statement

Comment: Thanks it worked on my shell, but it didn't do quite what I wanted it to do in my template. I'll post another question.